# Oozie import workflow from command line (Cloudera)

Tags: cloudera, oozie

I am attempting to create oozie workflows from templates that can be pushed into a workspace.

I have the process in place as far as getting the workflow into the right place in HDFS and if I call

```
oozie job -oozie http://hostname:11000/oozie -config config.xml -submit
```

then call the `-start` command on the oozie commmand line with the returned job Id the job runs successfully.

Ideally, I'd like the workflow definition to now be available in the workflow manager. This can be done through Hue using the import button on the workflow manager dashboard (`http://hostname:8888/oozie/list_workflows/`) but I want to import the definition from a script.

Is this possible and if so how do I do it?